# Cобытие onclick + клавиша

Tags: javascript, jquery

Использую magnet для перетаскивания картинок.

```
$('#add_frieze_gor').on('click', () => {
                $('<img onclick="rotateBy10Deg(this)" class="magnet" src="images/tiles/'+$("#tiles_arr").val()+'.png">').appendTo('#container');
                $magnet.add(
                    document.querySelectorAll('.magnet')
                    
                );
            });
```

Решил добавить возможность поворота картинки.

```
var delta =0;
function rotateBy10Deg(ele){
  ele.style.webkitTransform="rotate("+delta+"deg)";
  delta+=10;
}
```

Возникло 2 вопроса.

1. Только при первом добавлении картинки ширина и высота ее равна нулю. При повторном добавлении все становится ок. Не понимаю почему с первого раза не отрабатывает нормально.
2. При перетаскивании картинок туда-сюда, она еще и поворачивается, т.е onclick на поворот отрабатывает. Можно ли добавить клавишу с клавиатуры. Shift+клик = поворот картинки - можно так сделать?

Comment: А как и когда вы проверяете высоту и ширину картинки?

Comment: А это необходимо? Я думал тут работает, как обычно. Воткнул img в html код и картинка появилась с оригинальными размерами. Тут же со второго раза тоже все отрабатывает. Я смотрел что-то подобное, но до появления картинки на сайте я жене могу узнать ее размеры.

Comment: imageElement.naturalHeight - что-то подобное находил

Comment: Да так и работает. И сложно понять почему у вас сразу не отрабатывает без воспроизводимого примера.

Comment: http://simvl.ru/light/test/construct.html
Сделал тестовую страницу
Только при повторном нажатии на добавить элемент, добавляется картинка.
Shift уже прикрутил.

Comment: Есть подозрение что это происходит из за того что при первом клике картинка еще не загружена и поэтому добавляется с шириной и высотой 0. А потом она кешируется браузером и последующие клики отрабатывают нормально. Вот похожую тему разбирают: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13412982/jquery-img-width-gives-0